# Architecting a Solution with many Sites within a Site (Chapters) - How many sections can Craft Handle?

Tags: sections, contentmodel

I am working on a plan for a site build that includes national content as well as many chapters' content. The latter has a number of requirements that are leading me to using separate sections including a structure for general pages and news, and events channels.

So looking at 3 sections per chapter and starting with around 20 chapters with more to come over time.

I am not worried about the manual setup of these (albeit it's not ideal); however, I am concerned about hitting limits either in the interface and/or performance of Craft that I just may not be as familiar with.

As chapter numbers grow, will this be too many sections for Craft to handle?

Comment: If the 3 sections per chapter are all basically the same 3 identical section, why not just have 3 sections **period**? Then you could use something like Categories to identify which entries belong to which chapter.

Comment: @LindseyD I am exploring that as well; however, there are permission issues at play here, too. Would make a lengthy post to share all the details.

Comment: Interesting, factoring in permissions would certainly complicate things. You may be able to separate based on user groups (instead of categories), but that probably brings its own set of complications.

Comment: This doesn't directly address the limits, but the manual setup. [The Architect plugin](https://github.com/Pennebaker/craftcms-thearchitect) can help with the manual setup. As long as the models are the same for each chapter, you can export the structures and entryTypes to a .json doc, and then store them in one of the plugin's folders. Every time you need to make a chapter, copy the .json model, update it to configure chapter info, and reimport it. Should cut down on time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As chapter numbers grow, will this be too many sections for Craft to handle?

Probably not.  I suspect as your section list grows to the multi-thousand section range (if it will ever get that large), you'll start to run into MySQL/environmental limitations rather than any Craft ones.  But if  you do run into any UI/architectural limitations, we'd love to hear about them.

In the upcoming Craft 2.3 release, we spent a great deal of time addressing UI scaling issues around Structured Sections and Categories when they start to approach the multi-thousand range, but we've seem installations with several hundred thousands of Channel entries/assets/users running just fine.